# AutoCompleteTextView Drop Down list shows empty textViews

Tags: android, mysql, autocompletetextview

I have written the following code for populating the AutoCompleteTextView from a MySQL database using internet. The database returns data and autocompletetextView adapter contains that data, however the drop down list shows empty cells.

```
if(suggestionList != null)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contains Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,suggestionList);
    searchBox.setAdapter(adapter);

    for(int i=0; i<suggestionList.length;i++)
            System.out.println(suggestionList[i]);
}
```

**NOTE:
SuggestionList is a String array and contains all the data**

What can be the issue here?

Regards

Comment: Is that values are printing?

Comment: yes. correct values are being printed in console

Answer (score 0):

Try adding items to your adapter manually. 
For example:

```
adapter.add("Item 1");
```

Refer to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add%28T%29) for adding items in the list view.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I have passed the data to ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, suggestionList);
searchBox.setAdapter(adapter);
searchBox.setThreshold(1);
```